# ST-Link refuses to find my STM32F3 discovery board

Tags: stm32, embedded, windows

The [ST-Link Utility software](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link004.html) I installed doesn't recognize the board. It looks like I connected the board before installing drivers and even after multiple trials of installing and uninstallling the drivers the problem remains. The device manager shows an unknown device with broken driver. My OS is Windows 7.

I am using Atollic IDE for development.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Basically you just plug it in, driver gets installed, everything fine. You do not need to install the driver before you connect the board.

Comment: Remove all driver you have manually installed, and just plug in the board and let Windows (I assume you are on Windows but you should have included your OS) find the proper driver.

Comment: No, no drivers were installed except there was one I saw under "Programs and Features" it is for 3d accelerometer sensor. I removed all the USB drivers particular for this board that installed from the Stlink utility then plugged back in and there was no reinstallation of the drivers

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: OS: I use Windows 7

Comment: And just to be clear the board in question is http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html

Comment: Actually STM32F3 discovery is the board

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right USB? That discovery board has two USBs, one connected to ST-Link the other is directly to the MCU. Please check if VID and PID are avialable. I have a Nucleo and ST-Link v2.1 plugged in right now, one is 0483:374b the other is 0483:374b.

Comment: The board is this one: http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f3discovery.html ?

Comment: @JanDorniak  what are the VID and PID ?

Comment: @JanDorniak Another thing I noticed, the COM LED is blinking red

Comment: I vote to leave this question open because the OP needs help with EE software specifically. Such questions should be on topic here.